# Managing complex unit test mock data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I would like to make unit tests for code that relies on a rather complex database structure (nested, circular references etc.). Normally I would do something like this:

```
var personRepository = new Mock<IPersonRepository>();
personRepository.Setup(r => r.GetPerson()).Returns(
new Person() 
{ 
    FirstName = "Joe",
    LastName = "Smith"
});
```

The problem with my "complex" data is that I feel like my tests gets cluttered with the mock data. What are my options? I thought about saving the data as .json files, which I guess could work. Ideally, I would like to use an in memory representation of a database snapshot. Is it possible using EF6? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not extract your complex test data representation into a separate class or create a factory method?

Comment: @DanielMann You mean managing the mock data in something like a test helper class?

Comment: Exactly. In my experience, pulling test data out of code and into some other representation (be it JSON, XML, excel spreadsheets, whatever) does nothing to increase maintainability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com/), which was designed to allow you to unit test code that uses Entity Framework.

It will look at your database and construct an in-memory version that acts like the real thing, but that can be recreated for each test. You could then write some code that will populate the pseudo database with your data, allowing you to test it.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Can the in memory database be populated from an actual database?

Comment: @filur I suppose you could do that manually by writing code to query the database, but that would go away form the idea of unit testing, which is supposed to be independent of such things. I think the idea is to write some code to populate the Effort database, so you always start your uni tests with a known state. Populating from a real database would be uncertain, as it would depend on the database not changing. If your data is in a database, you could write a one-off script to generate the C# to populate the Effort database. Done that sort of thing.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about having a designated test database to load the data from. It was possible to use with one of their dataloaders.

Comment: @filur I don't think Effort comes with that built in, and I imagine it would slow your unit tests down. I would populate from code.